# Unexpected (not helpful) result on first run of sp_BlitzIndex

Tags: sql-server, sp-blitzindex

I just ran sp_BlitzIndex for the first time and got 1 row:

```
Priority=-1, 
Finding=sp_BlitzIndex(TM) v5.7 - September 01, 2017: All Databases,
Database Name=NULL, 
Details: schema.table.index(indexed)=http://FirstResponderKit.org, 
URL=From Your Community Volunteers
```

Environment information:

- sp_BlitzIndex version: 5.7
- SQL Server version: 2008 R2 (SP2), 10.50.4000.0 (X64)
- Operating System: Windows 2008 T2, SP1

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about how you ran the command?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you ran it with @GetAllDatabases = 1, and an error occurred. For example, you may have more than 50 databases on your system, or it may have encountered a dynamic SQL problem.

When you're troubleshooting why a query doesn't produce the results you expected, head on over to the Messages tab in SSMS.